# The selected JRE does not support compiler compliance level of 1.5

Tags: java, blackberry

i have created my project in blackerry 7. 
when try to run project it shows "Project can not be packaged because it does not have a BlackBerry JRE associated.Unknown BlackBerry Packaging Problem"
i have selected compiler 1.4. I have used classes like Vector it shows error that change compiler compliance level to 1.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that your project is using the Blackberry JRE/JDE in the Build Path, and not standard Java JRE. Compiler compliance should be 1.3 with Blackberry projects (AFAIK, unless this has changed with BB JDE 7), the reason you're asked to change the level to 1.5 is probably that you have standard JRE defined in the Build Path and you're trying to use generics (`Vector<SomeClass>`) which are not available before Java 1.5 (and thus cannot be used in BlackBerry -projects).

Comment: so What should i do to use vectors in blackberry projects?

Comment: @JoVinz Sorry, I had forgot to add the code-markings, so the generics-part between `<` and `>` didn't show. What I meant is you can't use generics (like `Vector<SomeClass>`) in Blackberry, but you can use "normal" java.util.Vector (no type safety, just plain `Vector` without the generics-part, so it acts just same as `Vector<Object>`). Just make sure you have set the correct JRE (The Blackberry one) in the projects' build path and the code compliance is set to Java 1.3.

Comment: I want to use this :HashMap<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>    how can i use this?

Comment: @JoVinz: Unfortunately, you can't. First of all, as said, Blackberry doesn't support Java 1.5's features, like generics (the parts between `<` and `>`), and also, doesn't have HashMap. The closest is probably HashTable, see here:  http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/java/util/Hashtable.html

Comment: Whats the way to use Map inside Hashmap? i mean is there any other way to do it?

Comment: @JoVinz: Most Collection-implementations (including Map-interface implementations like HashMap) that are available in Java SE and EE are missing completely from Blackberry and other Java ME-environments. You could store HashTables inside HashTables, but that can get quite complicated and/or heavy for the device. Maybe you should consider redesigning your data model to a simpler one.